# When adding SpaCy output to existing dataframe, columns do not align

Tags: python, pandas, spacy

I have a csv with a column of article titles from which I've used SpaCy to extract any people's names that appear in the titles. When trying to add a new column to the csv with the names extracted by SpaCy, they do not align with the rows from which they were extracted.

I believe this is because the SpaCy results have their own index which is independent of the original data's index.

I've tried adding `, index=df.index)` to the new column line but I get "ValueError: Length of passed values is 2, index implies 10."

How do I align the SpaCy output to the rows from which they originated?

Here's my code:

```
import pandas as pd
from pandas import DataFrame
df = (pd.read_csv(r"C:\Users\Admin\Downloads\itsnicethat (5).csv", nrows=10,
                  usecols=['article_title']))
article = [_ for _ in df['article_title']]

import spacy
nlp = spacy.load('en_core_web_lg')
doc = nlp(str(article))
ents = list(doc.ents)
people = []
for ent in ents:
    if ent.label_ == "PERSON":
        people.append(ent)

import numpy as np
df['artist_names'] = pd.Series(people)
print(df.head())
```

This is the resulting dataframe:

```
                                       article_title       artist_names
0  “They’re like, is that? Oh it’s!” – ...               (Hannah, Ward)
1  Billed as London’s biggest public festival of ...  (Dylan, Mulvaney)
2  Transport yourself back to the dusky skies and...                NaN
3  Turning to art at the beginning of quarantine ...                NaN
4  Dylan Mulvaney, head of design at Gretel, expl...                NaN
```

This is what I'm expecting:

```
                                       article_title       artist_names
0  “They’re like, is that? Oh it’s!” – ...               (Hannah, Ward)
1  Billed as London’s biggest public festival of ...                NaN
2  Transport yourself back to the dusky skies and...                NaN
3  Turning to art at the beginning of quarantine ...                NaN
4  Dylan Mulvaney, head of design at Gretel, expl...   (Dylan, Mulvaney)
```

You can see the 5th value in artist_names column is related to the 5th article title. How can I get them to align?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would iterate through the articles, detect entities from each article separately, and put the detected entities in a list with one element per article:

```py
nlp = spacy.load('en_core_web_lg')
article = [_ for _ in df['article_title']]

entities_by_article = []
for doc in nlp.pipe(article):
  people = []
  for ent in doc.ents:
    if ent.label_ == "PERSON":
      people.append(ent)
  entities_by_article.append(people)

df['artist_names'] = pd.Series(entities_by_article)
```

Note: `for doc in nlp.pipe(article)` is spaCy's more efficient way of looping through a list of texts and could be replaced by:

```py
for a in article:
  doc = nlp(a)
  ## rest of code within loop
```

Comment: This did the trick - thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

```
    if ent.label_ == "PERSON":
        people.append(ent)
    else:
        people.append(np.nan) # if ent.label_ is not a PERSON
```

include an else statement so if label_ is not PERSON it will be consider as NaN.

Comment: I did try this at first, but it just returns NaN for all instances of no PERSON listed above the data frame rather than in the correct order.